# Mac Terminal Curl for textfile

Tags: macos, curl

I am trying to download a CSV file from a local webserver (the webserver runs on a signal conditioning instrument) with:

```
curl -O http://10.0.0.139/crv01.csv
```

The output from curl is only weird symbols. If I put the same url in Safari the CSV File is correctly depicted. Is there any encoding problem with curl?

I tried the verbose option which gives:

```
Gunthers-MacBook-Pro:Documents guenther$ curl -v -O http://10.0.0.141/crv01.csv
* About to connect() to 10.0.0.141 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.0.0.141...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connected
* Connected to 10.0.0.141 (10.0.0.141) port 80 (#0)
> GET /crv01.csv HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: 10.0.0.141
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon Aug 26 21:03:12 2013
< Server: VEGA-HTTP-SERVER
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
< Content-type: text/plain
< Connection: Close
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Length: 226
< 
{ [data not shown]
100   226  100   226    0     0   1883      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1965
* Closing connection #0
Gunthers-MacBook-Pro:Documents guenther$ vi crv01.csv

^_<8b>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^C}<92>Á
<83>0^L<86>ï<82>ï xÙ^N+I;kkO²<95>!l^N6õ-ÆÞÿ¶zÐ¤¬4Ç~$ÿ<9f>?­_~^YÞÃs¬P@YÔ<97>ùµø
ÐMýí4~E<85>áñÚOÞMÃÃ»¥¿Ïþð9<96><85>l^D^X!^A<95>CÛ)Õ¡uR´^RBETB<96>b<96>J¢^X^F^G<87>LWª^?ªwWÀt·^F<99>n<82>&tY/Ó]M­®^X=g]5D^S½:KÛ,5;Õv^]^]®À\Ù^\EÈRÌRÊ*¡<8b><94>U<8a>RV)JY¥(e¥^M<84><8a>öEÊ*E^Mmd TÜk<89>¶^AÆ÷eÿy<9b>ü^C»üß{E^C^@^@
```

Source Code of the webpage (Google Chrome) is a plain cdv file. CSV File is create by 
http://www.vega.com/en/Signal-conditioning-instrument-VEGAMET391.htm

The --text-ascii option also did not help!

Comment: What are you using for your local server? Apache? Node? nginx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the page is sent back compressed (see the header "Content-Encoding: gzip") even though curl didn't ask for it. If you ask for it, curl will decompress it for you automatically when receiving it. Try:

```
curl --compressed -O http://10.0.0.139/crv01.csv
```

Comment: So, is there any reason cURL doesn't do this automatically? :-)

Comment: @NicholasRiley: curl's basic philosophy is to do the simple things by default and allow users to enable more fancy if desired, this is in line with that.

Answer (score 0):

That command should work, it works correctly on my system (10.6) when serving a csv file locally.

You could try the command with verbose on to see if there is any issue:

```
curl -v -O http://10.0.0.139/crv01.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

How was the CSV created? By Excel or was it always native text? I suspect Safari is rendering while ignoring extraneous binary data.

You could View Source in Safari and make sure it is plain.

Also try `curl --trace-ascii` to request ASCII context.

**Edit:**
From your verbose output, it looks like the file is gzipped. 
Try saving it as a `.gz` file instead and then `gunzip crv01.gz`

```
curl http://10.0.0.139/crv01.csv -o crv01.gz
gunzip crv01.gz
```

If there are more `crv` files, you can also download a range of them at once:

```
curl "http://10.0.0.139/crv[01-50].csv" -o crv#1.gz
```